# Operating a switch mode power supply at its limits

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I have a few SMPSs with over current protection.

When reaching the maximum power output they simply start dropping the voltage.

I am powering LEDs and the alternative would be to add a small resistor in series.  The power heating the resistor would however be lost.

Is it safe and power efficient to operate SMPS at their limits?

If this depends on the PS (maybe the IC) is there an easy way to know which PSs I can use this way and which not?

If it's not safe / power efficient, why?

Comment: "simply dropping the current" doesn't sound like overcurrent protection; that's kicks in later. That's just you overtasking the SMPS. Anyway, SMPSes come in very different architectures, and no statement about the efficiency can be made without knowing exactly which architecture, with which components, going from which to which voltage... So, we can't even say which "kind" of SMPS you need to use, as that depends on many factors. You'll notice that very similar SMPSes have wildly different efficiency curves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does depend on the design of the power supply.

Unfortunately many power supplies are poorly designed and either can't put out their rated power continuously or can't operate at current limit continuously and reliably.

The only ways to know for sure are:

1. Contact the manufacturer to see if they have data showing reliability (including temperature rise on critical components) in current limit along with lifetime and reliability predictions or testing.
2. Run your own tests on the supply, instrumenting temperatures of critical components.  If you can, run the tests at high ambient in a thermal chamber.
3. Reverse engineer the supply and analyze it to see if it should be reliable.

I have tested many wall adapter supplies in this way, all within their rated specs and a high percentage of them permanently failed, so try to get your supplies from a quality supplier.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it safe and power efficient to operate SMPS at their limits?

Yes, but not safe to operate them above their limits. Although an SMPS with appropriate testing should be able to handle a direct short.

> If this depends on the PS (maybe the IC) is there an easy way to know
>   which PSs I can use this way and which not?

Check the datasheet, make sure it has the appropriate [ETL certifications](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj9renq6bzbAhWNr1kKHZrfCMsQFghYMAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cui.com%2Fcatalog%2Fresource%2Fpower-supply-safety-standards-agencies-and-marks.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1wJqRtxafo0NeCLcNyhscu) (UL ect). Buy from a reputible company (ie, a cheaper supply one area they usually save money on is the testing and components). All supplies that are tested to IEC standards are tested to the following (and a few more that I will not list):
1) Make sure that there is appropriate insulation or gaps for high voltage sections in the PCB, cables and components
2) Components that are above a certain voltage (mains voltage) have to be tested under additional ETL requirements
3) A fault won't shock the user
4) The supply can handle shorts at the rated current without overheating or destructing

> If it's not safe / power efficient, why?

Power efficiency has nothing do do with saftey of the design. And at DC, the supply doesn't care what kind of load you place on it. If you have something that is switching on and off this can become a problem. IF you really want a safe supply then get a medical grade supply.

Comment: "power efficiency has nothing to do with safety" Well, technically, a sufficiently inefficient device could rise to an unsafe temperature.... That's just pedantry, though :P

Comment: If the supply is rated for a certain amperage, then it doesn't matter how efficient it is at delivering that current, and if it has a current rating, then that means there has been some sort of testing to make sure that it can deliver that current safely

Answer (score 0):

> Is it safe and power efficient to operate SMPS at their limits?

Let's say a certain manufacturer said something like: -

```
Can be operated indefinitely into and out of current overload protection at any temperature
```

So, going back to your requirement: -

> I am powering LEDs and the alternative would be to add a small
>   resistor in series. The power heating the resistor would however be
>   lost.

Without an active limiting device like a resistor you would be relying on the current limiting circuit designed to protect the power supply and, is there any guarantee that this will operate reliably at a certain limit and act immediately?

Not acting immediately might mean that when the supply goes into "current limit" it oscillates in a loop such that only the average current at the output is limited. This would be a disaster for LEDs running close to their own limits. The current could exceed the peak LED current cyclically.

Also, who guarantees that a current limiter won't change its characteristic limit value at different temperatures. Who is going to guarantee that?

> is there an easy way to know which PSs I can use this way and which
>   not?

Not even by "black box" testing can this be properly known.